# Was this improvement necessary or required?

Tags: discussion

I came across [this edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1081972/2) by abu_bua. I just want to know what is the use of this edit or was it even needed or is it just for increasing the numbers?

**PS**: No personal differences with abu_bua. Just asking for the sake of knowledge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This edit was adding a bold face to the word 'after'.  It was not necessary.

I have reverted the edit manually as adding bold to a single word in the context it was in was not necessary.